# How to get input inside textfield here?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript. I just want to take input in the created textfield.

So that I created a **ul tag** with id cstList.

and called a function **listData()** on the onclick event

Inside that I am trying to create a **input tag** inside a **div tag.**

After creation I am not able to type in the textfield.

Can anybody tell me, why is it so?

Here is my **listData()** code

```
function listData()
    {       
        //var a = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
        if(sessionStorage == null)
        {
            alert("Session storage not supported here");
        }
        else
        {
            var ss = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
            alert("storage value is: "+ss);
        }
    var rows = prompt('Please type in the number of required rows');
    var listCode = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var listID = 'list_' + i.toString();
        var divID = 'div_' + i.toString();
        var inputIdp = 'inputp_'+ i.toString();
        var inputIdq = 'inputq_'+ i.toString();
          //  listCode += '<li id="' + listID + '><div id = "'+ divID + '"> <input type= "text" id= "boltQTY" name= "boltQTY" value = "abc"/> <input type= "text" id= "a" name= "boltQTY" value = "abc" size="5"/></div></li>';

          listCode += "<li id='" + listID + "'><div id = '"+ divID + "'> <input type='text' id='" + inputIdp + "' name='" + inputIdp + "' value='' size='15'/> <input type='text' id='" + inputIdq + "' name='" + inputIdq + "' value='' size='15'/> </div></li>";

            //variable = "string" + var1 + "string=' " + var2 +"' ";
    }
    document.getElementById('cstList').innerHTML = listCode;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use www.jsfiddle.net? Developers will be able to help you better. :)

Comment: let me post ma code on jsfiddle

Comment: guys its working very fine on jsfiddle. so what would be the problem?

Comment: @nick can you give the page link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/narendra64/vWx6x/1/

Comment: I am using Google chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer. That was the issue with the iscroll, discussed on the group.google.com.

Resolved the problem of entering the value in text field by the below code.

Create this code in new **js** file.

```
iScroll.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
    var that = this,
        hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window && !isTouchPad,
        vendor = (/webkit/i).test(navigator.appVersion) ? 'webkit' :
                 (/firefox/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'Moz' :
                 'opera' in window ? 'O' : '',
        RESIZE_EV = 'onorientationchange' in window ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize',
        START_EV = hasTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
        MOVE_EV = hasTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
        END_EV = hasTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup',
        CANCEL_EV = hasTouch ? 'touchcancel' : 'mouseup',
        WHEEL_EV = vendor == 'Moz' ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel';

    switch(e.type) {
        case START_EV:
            if (that.checkInputs(e.target.tagName)) {
                return;
            }

            if (!hasTouch && e.button !== 0) return;

            that._start(e);
            break;
        case MOVE_EV: 
            that._move(e); 
            break;
        case END_EV:
            if (that.checkInputs(e.target.tagName)) {
                return;
            }
        case CANCEL_EV: 
            that._end(e);
            break;
        case RESIZE_EV: 
            that._resize();
            break;
        case WHEEL_EV: 
            that._wheel(e); 
            break;
        case 'mouseout': 
            that._mouseout(e); 
            break;
        case 'webkitTransitionEnd': 
            that._transitionEnd(e); 
            break;
    }
}

iScroll.prototype.checkInputs = function(tagName) {
    if (tagName === 'INPUT' || tagName === 'TEXTFIELD' || tagName === 'SELECT') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```